# SCCM How can I add Computer Name in this code?

Tags: sql, sccm

The purpose of the code; List the viruses/threats on computers that are in the  System Center. But I can't add Computer Name in this code. It won't works. How can we do this?

```
Select distinct 

t.DetectionID,
t.DetectionTime,
IsNULL(tc.Name,t.ThreatName) as ThreatName, 
cat.Category,
sev.Severity,
t.PendingActions,
t.Process,
t.UserName,
t.Path,
t.CleaningAction,
t.ActionSuccess,
t.DetectionSource

from fn_rbac_R_System(@UserSIDs)  s 
join fn_rbac_GS_Threats(@UserSIDs)  t on s.ResourceID=t.ResourceID
left join fn_rbac_ThreatCatalog(@UserSIDs)  tc on t.ThreatID=tc.ThreatID
left join fn_rbac_ThreatSeverities(@UserSIDs)  sev on tc.SeverityID=sev.SeverityID 
left join fn_rbac_ThreatCategories(@UserSIDs)  cat on tc.CategoryID=cat.CategoryID

where t.DetectionID <> 'Null'

order by t.DetectionTime DESC
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting? normally it would in a collumn s.Name0 in your example

Comment: I could not see that :) Thank you very much.

Comment: Great, then I will rewrite this as an answer so the question does not appear unanswered

Comment: Off course. You do that. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In contrast to fn_rbac_GS_Threats in the function fn_rbac_R_System (and the underlying view v_R_System) most columns are named with a trailing 0, so the property you are looking for is Name0 in fn_rbac_R_System. (I think this is because in general those views are comprised of different datasources and to prevent multiple columns with the same name the names are always indexed even in cases where the name would already be unique).

So in your example it would need to be:

```
Select distinct 

s.Name0,
t.DetectionID,
t.DetectionTime,
IsNULL(tc.Name,t.ThreatName) as ThreatName, 
cat.Category,
sev.Severity,
t.PendingActions,
t.Process,
t.UserName,
t.Path,
t.CleaningAction,
t.ActionSuccess,
t.DetectionSource

from fn_rbac_R_System(@UserSIDs)  s 
join fn_rbac_GS_Threats(@UserSIDs)  t on s.ResourceID=t.ResourceID
left join fn_rbac_ThreatCatalog(@UserSIDs)  tc on t.ThreatID=tc.ThreatID
left join fn_rbac_ThreatSeverities(@UserSIDs)  sev on tc.SeverityID=sev.SeverityID 
left join fn_rbac_ThreatCategories(@UserSIDs)  cat on tc.CategoryID=cat.CategoryID

where t.DetectionID <> 'Null'

order by t.DetectionTime DESC
```